# java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory Exception com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: Error opening socket to server

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I am trying to execute JMeter test scripts in JMX file using Java code, I am getting below exception in result file after execution. My JMX file contains some JDC requests and JDBC connection configuration

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([jcc][t4][2043][11550][3.68.61] Exception com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: Error opening socket to server xxxxxx/xxxxx on port 50,005 with message: [jcc][t4][20133][12451][3.68.61] Caught NoSuchAlgorithmException while doing SSL Connection.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=null. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

JDBC Connections is SSL based in configuration in JMX. I am just rying to executed it from Java code in Non-GUI mode.

I checked JDK version everywhere, we are using eclipse so made changes in there too. Its integrated with maven project. I am expecting it to run in non-GUI mode and give results in XML

JDK version -1.8.0_261
Maven version - 3.6.2
Jmeter version - 5.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DB2 instance requires some form of client certificates so you need to create [keystore and truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference), put your client certificates there and configure JMeter to use these keystore and truststore via *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

More information:

- [Java Secure Socket Extension (JSSE) Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization)
- [Setting up SSL enabled JCC driver connection from Data Studio to DB2 server](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/setting-ssl-enabled-jcc-driver-connection-data-studio-db2-server)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I have sslConnection attribute needed mention in DB URL in DB Connection Configuration in JMX file. Do I still need to change system.properties? If yes, please specify what all fields need to be changed. DB URL looks something like this-
jdbc:db2://xxx:potNumber/DBName:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=path\\to\\keystore\\filename.jks;sslTrustStorePassword=password;sslTrustStoreType=JKS;